# How to Convert InputStream.read(new byte[1024]); to String?

Tags: java, inputstream

I would like to get data from `InputStream()` as a String eg. Hi, Start, Stop, etc.

My Code fragment is

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
inputStream.read(buffer);
```

My data is Command Sent from Bluetooth.
The above code fragment only get (eg. 2 if I sent Hi, 5 if sent Start), I would like to get back Normal String as the same from the Sender Side.

I found only converting way from String to `InputStream`.
any suggestion , I would like to appreciate!

Comment: C#? Java? Other? Adding these "clues" will make the question better.

Comment: You need to know the encoding of what you are receiving before you can convert it to a stream.

Answer (score 1):

finally, i can solve this!
inputStream.read(buffer); only return the int num of how many bytes is in the buffer and the data from the socket is stored in buffer. So, from the buffer you can make String 
eg. String result = new String (buffer);

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is via the [Apache common-io library](http://commons.apache.org/io/):

```
String input = IOUtils.toString(inputStream);
```

See the [javadoc for this method](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/index.html?org/apache/commons/io/package-summary.html) for more.